# Check if in image file there is hidden or added text(steganographia)

Tags: c#, image

I would like to find if there is hidden code in a png file.

I don't want to know what is the text or the code(malicious or otherwise) just want to know if there is code in the png file.

Can I make something like this?

I tried to catch corruption like this:

```
 private static bool isValidGDIPlusImage(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
            {
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But its not always catch the corruption only if the file cant open.

Comment: Why did you think that the constructor for a Bitmap image would perform these checks for you?  Imagine the wasted resources for checking this on every Bitmap image opened around the world where nobody cared about your use case

Comment: The point of steganography is that the image _is_ still a valid image and can be opened, displayed, etc ...

Comment: you right I am trying to find better way

Comment: [You might want to read through this](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html) (and the next couple of pages there) if you want to check the internals of PNG files, rather than use a class specifically _meant_ to treat any of about a dozen image types it can load as being the same thing.